# how to subquery with filters in jena sparql?

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, tdb

I am trying to apply a Subquery in filters in Jena Sparql.Is this possible.If yes,how?eg:

```
SELECT ?x WHERE(?y <xyz:> ?z . ?y <abc:> ?x .FILTER regex(?z,subquery,"i")}
```

I mean I want to give the expression in filter using some subquery in jena..How Can I do it?If not whats its replacement?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, @cooljohny.  You won't be able to embed the subquery right in filter expression, but you can certainly use a subquery to provide the values that you'll use in the filter expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put the subquery in the filter expression, because the subquery isn't an expression with a value. You can use a subquery to provide the values that you use in a filter expression, though.  E.g.,

```
# Find persons whose names are also the names of flowers (Rose, Daisy, etc.) by
# performing a subquery to find all the flower names, and then finding people 
# whose names match those names.
select ?person where {
  ?person a :Person ;
          :name ?name .
  filter regex(?name,?flowerName, "i" )

  { select ?flowerName { ?flower a :Flower ; :name ?flowerName } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..this is exactly what I wanted...just one more doubt, in the regex filter the pattern I match for is <CAAD0KRhXUUwNjcAhc+4h-ftiJFW7q0y9gmDRGZ0khzyzWUDxbQ@mail.gmail.com> and it is there in the database but when I query it using filter it gives nothing. Are there any restrictions on pattern in regex filters such as characters like + - . @ cannot be used?

Comment: @cooljohny well, it is a regexp, so characters like + typically mean `"at least one".  If you're looking for an exact match, there's no reason to use a regexp, though;  just query for the exact value.

Comment: actually I am not looking for an exact match..its just a part of the whole string and if my pattern contains + etc what can I do?

Comment: If it's just containment, use the [contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-contains) function.  That should be cheaper than doing a regex.

Comment: But I don't want true or false as answer I want to query using thatWhat could be the replacement of regex(If I want to use + etc)?

Comment: "But I don't want true or false as answer"  I don't understand what you're asking.  regex returns true or false, just like contains does.  If you're looking for, e.g., `?name` that contains `?flowerName`, you just do `filter contains( ?name, ?flowerName )`.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood something..an once again Thanks ! I really appreciate your help and you really helped me a lot with all my questions. :)